# Added variable(s) does not support value initialization Exception

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here...

The code:

```
@Composable
internal fun ReceiptsScreen(navigator: Navigator, provider: IdentityProviderClient) {

    val receipts: List<Receipt> = receiptsService.getReceipts()
    mainScaffold("Receipts", 1)
    {
        val paddingModifier = Modifier.padding(3.dp)

        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState(), enabled = true),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        ) {
            items(receipts.size) {
                Card(
                    elevation = 10.dp,
                    contentColor = Color.Blue,
                    modifier = paddingModifier
                ) {
                    receipts[it]
...
```

```
Added variable(s) does not support value initialization: Adding field object vieaw.screens.ReceiptsScreenKt$ReceiptsScreen$1.$receipts
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. It appears to be related to hot reloading failure. Simply stopping and running the app again got rid of this error for me.